# What is the correct term for this?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage, sentence-request

I was in my hall and heard my brother's mobile phone ring, but as soon as he could come upstairs, the phone stopped ringing.

What term/phrase is used when the other person disconnects before you pick up the call?

I usually say

> The phone got cut

But I'm aware that this is wrong

I can't use disconnected either because it is normally used when the person is in the process of talking

> I was *talking* to my friend and the phone *disconnected*

So how do I tell this? I'd like a more formal way of saying it

Comment: You already used the phrase that is the most common: *the phone stopped ringing.*

Comment: Also you'll hear "I missed your call", "I just missed your call" and "I just missed your call by seconds"